# Get String in Assembly without Load it

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-assembly

I'm loading an Assembly dinamically using:

```
Assembly _assembly = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(PathToDllAssembly);
```

And I can check the Class and/or Methods names.

In order to access Methods i have to Load the assembly:

```
Assembly _assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(PathToDllAssembly);
```

**But it is possible to get a `String` value inside the Assembly without actually load it or load it in a ReflectionOnly context?**

**Edit:**
Just so you know and maybe you can point me in the right direction, I'm asking that because inside my Assembly I have `key` String, it is an encrypted string, and I only want to load that assembly if decrypted `key` is equal to a string.

It is a sort of little protection I'm trying to implement.

Comment: If you want a string that is part of the class, you'll have to load the given assembly.

Comment: One thing you could do is load the assembly in to a [new AppDomain](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130766(v=vs.110).aspx) without any rights (`new PermissionSet(PermissionState.None);`), read the string, then if it is correct load it in to your main AppDomain.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the `ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom` [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.reflectiononlyloadfrom%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> You cannot execute code from an assembly that has been loaded into the
>   reflection-only context. To execute the code, load the assembly with
>   the LoadFile method.

Accessing the value of a field or property, or invoking a method, is executing the code.  As such, you have to use `LoadFile`.

As for your security measures, perhaps you should instead look at [assembly signing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc31ft41%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to properly verify the authenticity of your target assemblies.